# Why date.toLocalString() returns two different format?

Tags: javascript

So i am using `Date.toLocaleString()` to get time in particular time zone, but i am facing a issue, it is returning two different date format on two different os

```js
let currentTimeInSGT = new Date().toLocaleString('SG', {
  timeZone: 'Asia/Singapore',
  hour12: false
})
console.log(currentTimeInSGT)
```

On windows it returns

`7/18/2019, 19:19:32`

On ubuntu it returns

`18/07/2019, 19:19:32`

both of them are tested on chrome, and also value between browser also varies firefox and chrome also gives different format

How can i get consistent date time format ?

Comment: is "sg" a valid locale? If it's invalid, I think it uses the default settings, hence the inconsistency

Comment: Is "SG" supposed to mean Singapore? SG is [Sango language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sango_language). You need "language-locale" instead, e.g. "en-sg".

Comment: @JJJ  but still why i am getting different output when i use on same browser different os any idea ,

Comment: Because you haven't specified a locale, only a language.

Comment: @JJJ omg indeed a silly mistake, thanks mate for your time and help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `sg` as your locale, you should probably use `en-SG`, as [that seems to be the accepted pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString#Using_locales).

That produced the same results on all browsers I've checked. (Chrome, Firefox, Edge)

```js
let currentTimeInSGT = new Date().toLocaleString('en-SG', {
  timeZone: 'Asia/Singapore',
  hour12: false
})

console.log(currentTimeInSGT)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer :) can you tell me OS you tested on ?

Comment: Windows 10 Enterprise / Version 1903 / OS build 18362.175

Answer (score -1):

The localeString uses the system settings to determine in which format it should be returned, every method marked with locale will show this behaviour in Javascript.

You can use toISOString to consistently convert your date to strings

EDIT: did not see java script tag